# Override css in html.DisplayFor mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web

I have a partial for example:

```
<div id="box1" class="test1"> 
@Model.Name
</div>
```

I call it from my main page using Html.DisplayFor

```
  <span>
  @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Name)
  </span>
```

However, I have another css class called "test2". Is there any way that I can pass in the test 2 css class through the html.DisplayFor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "test2" })
```

and in your display template

```
<div id="box1" class="test1 @ViewData["class"]"> 
    @Model.Name
</div>
```

What you're doing is using the override of `DisplayFor` with the additional view data argument, then accessing the view data on the other side.

Comment: should it be like this: 
<div id="box1" class="@ViewData["class"]"> 
    @Model.Name
</div>

Comment: Ah I thought you wanted both. Either way, I hope you get the gist of what I mean!

Comment: Thank you, that is a great approach. I will try that and manage the size of the ViewData object